# CamanJS extremely slow on Android

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, camanjs

Im developing a Webapp for Android using [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/) and [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/).

HTML:

```
<ion-view class="menu-content" view-title="Filter">
    <ion-nav-buttons side="primary">
        <button class="button" ng-click="done()">
            Done
        </button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>
    <ion-content overflow-scroll="true">
        <div id="polaroid-filter-img" class="polaroid-filter-img">
            <canvas id="polaroid-filter-img-img" data-caman-hidpi-disabled="true"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div class="polaroid-filter-examples">
            <div ng-repeat="filter in filters" ng-click="performFilter(filter.id)" id="filter.id">
                <img id="{{filter.id}}" ng-src="{{filter.image}}" />
                <span>{{filter.name}}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

JavaScript:

```
angular.module("App.Polaroids-Edit-Filter")

.controller("PolaroidsEditFilterController", function ($scope, $stateParams, $ionicHistory, PolaroidsService, FiltersService) {
    $scope.polaroid = PolaroidsService.getPolaroid($stateParams.id, $stateParams.size);
    $scope.filters = FiltersService.getFilters();

    var canvas;
    var context;
    var image;
    var currentFilter = null;

    $scope.performFilter = function (id) {
        if (id != null && id != currentFilter) {
            if (currentFilter != null) {
                document.getElementById(currentFilter).style.border = "none";
            }

            document.getElementById(id).style.border = "solid #FF0000";

            if (id == "normal") {
                Caman(canvas, image, function () {
                    this.revert(false);
                    this.render(function () {
                        console.log("reset completed");
                    });
                });
            } else {
                if (id == "vintage") {
                    Caman(canvas, image, function () {
                        this.revert(false);
                        this.vintage();
                        this.render(function() {
                            console.log("vintage completed"); 
                        });
                    });
                } else if (id == "lomo") {
                    Caman(canvas, image, function () {
                        this.revert(false);
                        this.lomo();
                        this.render(function() {
                            console.log("lomo completed"); 
                        });
                    });
                } else if (id == "clarity") {
                    Caman(canvas, image, function () {
                        this.revert(false);
                        this.clarity();
                        this.render(function() {
                            console.log("clarity completed"); 
                        });
                    });
                } else if (id == "sinCity") {
                    Caman(canvas, image, function () {
                        this.revert(false);
                        this.sinCity();
                        this.render(function() {
                            console.log("sinCity completed"); 
                        });
                    });
                } else if (id == "sunrise") {
                    Caman(canvas, image, function () {
                        this.revert(false);
                        this.sunrise();
                        this.render(function() {
                            console.log("sunrise completed"); 
                        });
                    });
                } else if (id == "crossProcess") {
                    Caman(canvas, image, function () {
                        this.revert(false);
                        this.crossProcess();
                        this.render(function() {
                            console.log("crossProcess completed"); 
                        });
                    });
                } else if (id == "orangePeel") {
                    Caman(canvas, image, function () {
                        this.revert(false);
                        this.orangePeel();
                        this.render(function() {
                            console.log("orangePeel completed"); 
                        });
                    });
                } else if (id == "love") {
                    Caman(canvas, image, function () {
                        this.revert(false);
                        this.love();
                        this.render(function() {
                            console.log("love completed"); 
                        });
                    });
                } else if (id == "grungy") {
                    Caman(canvas, image, function () {
                        this.revert(false);
                        this.grungy();
                        this.render(function() {
                            console.log("grungy completed"); 
                        });
                    });
                } else if (id == "jarques") {
                    Caman(canvas, image, function () {
                        this.revert(false);
                        this.jarques();
                        this.render(function() {
                            console.log("jarques completed"); 
                        });
                    });
                } else if (id == "pinhole") {
                    Caman(canvas, image, function () {
                        this.revert(false);
                        this.pinhole();
                        this.render(function() {
                            console.log("pinhole completed"); 
                        });
                    });
                } else if (id == "oldBoot") {
                    Caman(canvas, image, function () {
                        this.revert(false);
                        this.oldBoot();
                        this.render(function() {
                            console.log("oldBoot completed"); 
                        });
                    });
                } else if (id == "glowingSun") {
                    Caman(canvas, image, function () {
                        this.revert(false);
                        this.glowingSun();
                        this.render(function() {
                            console.log("glowingSun completed"); 
                        });
                    });
                } else if (id == "hazyDays") {
                    Caman(canvas, image, function () {
                        this.revert(false);
                        this.hazyDays();
                        this.render(function() {
                            console.log("hazyDays completed"); 
                        });
                    });
                } else if (id == "herMajesty") {
                    Caman(canvas, image, function () {
                        this.revert(false);
                        this.herMajesty();
                        this.render(function() {
                            console.log("herMajesty completed"); 
                        });
                    });
                } else if (id == "nostalgia") {
                    Caman(canvas, image, function () {
                        this.revert(false);
                        this.nostalgia();
                        this.render(function() {
                            console.log("nostalgia completed"); 
                        });
                    });
                } else if (id == "hemingway") {
                    Caman(canvas, image, function () {
                        this.revert(false);
                        this.hemingway();
                        this.render(function() {
                            console.log("hemingway completed"); 
                        });
                    });
                } else if (id == "concentrate") {
                    Caman(canvas, image, function () {
                        this.revert(false);
                        this.concentrate();
                        this.render(function() {
                            console.log("concentrate completed"); 
                        });
                    });
                }
            }

            currentFilter = id;
        }
    };

    $scope.done = function () {   
        if(currentFilter != null && currentFilter != "normal") {
            PolaroidsService.setFilter($stateParams.id, $stateParams.size, currentFilter);
            PolaroidsService.setFiltered($stateParams.id, $stateParams.size, canvas.toDataURL());
        }

        $ionicHistory.goBack(-1);
    };

    function initView() {
        var width = screen.width * 0.7;
        var height = width;
        var initialId = $scope.filters[0].id;

        currentFilter = initialId;

        document.getElementById("polaroid-filter-img").style.width = width + "px";
        document.getElementById("polaroid-filter-img").style.height = height + "px";
        document.getElementById(initialId).style.border = "solid #FF0000";

        canvas = document.getElementById("polaroid-filter-img-img");
        context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        image = new Image();

        image.crossOrigin = "";
        image.src = $scope.polaroid.cropped;
        image.onload = function () {
            canvas.width = image.width;
            canvas.height = image.height;
            context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
        }
    }

    var intervalId = setInterval(function () {
        initView();

        window.clearInterval(intervalId);
    }, 100);
});
```

If i now take a picture with my 8-megapixel and perform the vintage filter for example it takes over 14 seconds until the process is finished. That is too much long. No user will ever wait 14 seconds for that and filters on instagram for examples are performed instantly.

Smaller picutres like 200 x 200 pixels for example are also taking 3 to 4 seconds to be done.

How can it take so much time? Is there a solution for that?

Comment: canvas in general is slow on mobile devices, i tried using them for converting image to base64 format and it took like 8seconds :(

Comment: If that is true i should think about writing a native code plugin for that. Hmm... I dont like this...

Comment: well for one thing you can use CSS3 filters for visual representation, http://designpieces.com/2014/09/instagram-filters-css3-effects/ which would be much faster and just do the image processing in CamanJS in the background so the user doesn't have to wait for it

Comment: this could be a workaround indeed. thx for that.